# Bring several lines together to fill blank spaces in TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, sourcecode

Suppose in a TeXmaker document that looks like something like

```
phrase 1       phrase 2 phrase 3             phrase 100
```

or a sentence that looks like

```
A   quick brown    fox        jumps over     the lazy dog
```

I want them to look like

```
phrase 1 phrase 2 phrase 3 phrase 100
```

and

```
A  quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

in the latex document itself (not in the output pdf) i.e., with even gaps or in other words, remove unnecessary gaps. How do I do that? I want a single step process such as Ctrl+t comments out (or Ctrl+u restores it) several lines.

Comment: Put a blank line after each line? That is the universal law.

Comment: So you want to reduce the margin?

Comment: Alright, I see your edit. But why do you want to have it? One should change a paragraph in one-line code to multiple-line code. All documentations do so.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed my comments and made the question clearer. Does it make sense now?

Comment: oh clearer but _completely different_!! you do not want to change end-of-line to space you want to replace multiple spaces by a single space! I don't think anyone would ever have guessed that:-)  Someone will answer, I don't have texworks so I can't help, a regular-expression replace of ` +` to ` ` would work if it doesn't have a specific normalize-space function.

Comment: Is it possible that you typed a tab instead of a space in some places?

Comment: you can employ `latexindent.pl` to help with this. See https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-replacements.html#lst-phrase for example